# File Signature Validation (CryptQueryObject)

Tags: c++, c, winapi

Can we perform CryptQueryObject on a .dll files like (Kernel32.dll).

Trying this returns the error `CRYPT_E_NO_MATCH`.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot. If the signature is embedded this works, but the system dlls are validated against a signed catalog.